# Possible to imitate a wolf's howling with a simple electronic circuit?

Tags: design, sound

I would love to build a small circuit board that outputs something that sounds similar to a wolf howl to a small speaker. With "simple", I mean I would prefer if I could use simple components such as capacitors, resistors, coils and transistors etc rather than micro-controllers.

Is it possible to get close to a howling wolf without using a µC to playback a sample?

Comment: For anyone attempting this, some spectral analysis: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/11250008209439382  I would say that you should start with trying to replicate it on an FM synth and see if you can get close enough.

Comment: Oh man, so much MCU hate...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams MCU? Synonym for µC/microcontroller? It is for a school project and I don't want to spend much money on that. It is not just the costs for the µC, I also have no flashing/programming tools yet, so those would be expensive too. If I can close to that result with just some simple oscillator circuits, I would be happy.

Comment: @pjc50 Thank you for this interesting sheet. Would it be enough to create a small oscillator circuit for each peak in the frequency diagram and set them up parallel?

Comment: You can buy mp3 playback modules for like under ten on ebay. Or use an old mp3 player or cell phone.

Comment: Yes, but why not just process a MIDI or WAV computer file?

Comment: WAV = megabytes;  MIDI = events, not sounds.

Answer (score 6):

Get an ISD1610 voice recorder chip: -

[image]

If you can get a wolf sound thru your PC speakers, you can record it onto this device and it will playback whatever is recorded. It isn't hifi of course.

[digikey_link](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/ISD1610BSY/ISD1610BSY-ND/1232810).

Answer (score 1):

These days, a microcontroller is almost always the answer.

You can buy an [STM32F4 Discovery](http://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/STM32F4DISCOVERY/497-11455-ND/2711743) board for around USD$15 depending on the source.  The Discovery has a built-in STLINKv2 JTAG/SWD programmer.  The STM32F407 MCU that it mounts (an ARM Cortex-M4 that runs at up to 168MHz) could generate a wolf howl with a DMA-driven DAC while spending most of its time asleep.  You would still need to attach an amplifier if you want to drive a speaker directly, but you can make or buy an amp to drive a little 8-ohm speaker with an [LM386](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/NJM386D/NJM386D-ND/805736) for just a few $'s on breadboard or stripboard.

Use [this](http://www.coocox.org) free IDE for ARM Cortex-M's and (assuming that you already own some basic tools, including a soldering iron) you should be able to build something with serious wow factor (at a high school level) for under USD$25.

*Disclaimer: I have no relationship with ST or Coocox, I just think they have awesome products that are cheap or free.*

[edit] Or just buy a Raspberry Pi and use it to play an audio file into some PC speakers.